# How can you fill a table cell using Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, html-table

I'm trying to fill a table using the selenium drivers and all the documentations I could find only shows how to retrieve data from the cells. I'm able to access my table cells using:

```
var rows = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("Products")).FindElements(By.XPath("id('Products')/tbody/tr"));
var cells = tableRows[1].FindElements(By.XPath("td"));
```

But I couldn't find any way to update the data that's in it. The "Text" property only has a Get method and the SendKeys() function doesn't work. How can I edit the cell's value?

As a side note, my cell contains an html "input", I've tried to access it with the FindElement function of the cell but for some reasons it cannot find it.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, `SendKeys` should work if the cell indeed contains the input element. But because you're also saying that you fail to find the input element, I suspect that the input element does not exist in each cell all the time. You should probably first click on the cell in order for the input element to appear on that cell. You should be able to verify it using the Dev Tools if you inspect the element *before* clicking it.

Comment: That was the correct answer, the elements did not exist until I clicked on the line I wanted to update first. Then I could use the SendKeys function correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IWebElement doesn't provide a method to change text, but you could use a little bit of JS - something little like :

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementByXXXXX.innerHTML = "VALUE";");
```

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor_ExecuteScript.htm